# How to set CSS for border bottom

Tags: html, css

The problem is that

```
.sppb-nav-tabs {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5}
```

in my CSS works incorrect. I use this part of CSS for tabs on my web page and I would like them to look like they are at the moment. However when you switch between tabs, for example go from tab 1 to tab 2, there is `border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5` still there under selected tab until you click somewhere on content. Only after clicking somewhere outside of the tab `border-bottom-color: transparent;` is taking an affect. I have tried different solution with no success. Only by deleting `border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5` issue is getting fixed but then there is no line at all. Is there any ideas how to fix this issue?

```
.sppb-nav-tabs {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5}
.sppb-tab-content {
    margin-top: 15px}
.sppb-nav-tabs-content {
    margin-top: 0;
    border-left: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    background: #fff;
    border-top: 0;
    padding: 15px}
.sppb-nav-tabs>li {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: -1px}
.sppb-nav-tabs>li>a {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    padding: 12px 15px;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    color: inherit;
    border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border-right-width: 1px}
.sppb-nav-tabs>li: last-child>a {
    border-right-width: 1px}
.sppb-nav-tabs>li>a>i {
    margin-right: 5px}
.sppb-nav-tabs>li.active>a,.sppb-nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus,.sppb-nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover {
    color: inherit;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    cursor: default}
```

Comment: Why not just set `border-bottom-color: #ffffff` instead of `border-bottom-color: transparent`?

Comment: Thanks Chris! That worked for me. Sorry cant vote for your comment because of my low reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One more way to fix an issue is to edit a `bottom-border-color` attribute of selector (at line 1890 of sppagebuilder.css)

```
.sppb-nav-tabs>li.active>a,.sppb-nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus,.sppb-nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover
```

You need to replace `border-bottom-color: transparent;` with `border-bottom-color: #fff;`

Answer (score 0):

Check your :active state on line 3609 of template.css. When the anchor is being clicked, it's being given some important data. In chrome developer tools, try turning on the active state of the anchor, to see values affecting it during this state.

```
.next .pager a, a:hover, a:focus, a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
```